# Image compression techniques

Tags: compression

I'm interested on information on compression techniques that are suitable for images, where exact reproduction of the data is not necessary after decompression, as long as the result looks ok as an image. I've heard that there are, for example, fractal techniques that achieve much better compression on images than standard data compression techniques. Can anyone point me to some references to look up? How good compression can you get for different resolutions in typical images? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it just happen that this article has been published today comparing several open-source image compression implementations :

https://extrememoderate.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/a-web-centric-image-compression-benchmark/

As to algorithms, i would recommend you to start spending some time on Wikipedia, where a few good articles are available.
At the very least, you should have some basics in DCT and Wavelets theory before starting to look for more :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_transform#Wavelet_compression

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bit of a blog when I was working on [Wavelet Difference Reduction](http://www.trueharmoniccolours.co.uk/blog) a few years back.  It might be a useful read.  I'm really wishing OpenCL would support compiling C++ code because I'd love to convert it directly to OpenCL as its a beautifully parallelisable algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative which is easy to implement is *block truncation compression*, which was explained in Anton Kruger's article, "Block Truncation Compression", published in the XXX issue of "Dr. Dobb's Journal":

http://drdobbs.com/database/184408745?pgno=26

(Note that this article is extremely poorly formatted on DDJ's Web page.  It might be worth simply buying their DVD for a better copy.)

The basic idea is to limit luminance to 2 distinct values within small blocks of the image, and to represent those values with single bits.